# Delete a dataframe before re-assigning

Tags: r

I have a long R script that runs many SQL queries and assigns it to a dataframe names `df`. I don't delete the dataframe before re-assigning the result of another SQL query. Sometimes I receive some warnings that a column did not exist in `df` etc. There is nothing wrong with the results, but I was wondering whether it is a good practice to delete the dataframe before re-assigning a new dataset to it or it is not necessary?

**Sample code:**

```
sql <- "SELECT * FROM A"
df <- sqlQuery(db,sql)

''' do something '''

sql <- "SELECT * FROM B"
df <- sqlQuery(db,sql)

''' do something else '''
```

**example of the warning I get:**

```
Warning messages: 
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'Business'.  
2:Unknown or uninitialised column: 'Business'.  
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'Percentage'.
```

Business or Percentage are aliases that I assign in the query statement:

`sql <- "SELECT UserAssigned, DateAssigned, Vendor AS Business ...`

Comment: Could you please share those warning messages for further investigation?

Comment: When I manage lot of data and reassignee it in the same code I usually use gc() "garbage collector", incredibly, in my experience this simple thing a bunch of time get less warnings and faster program.

Comment: @SantiagoHurtado do you use it before each re-assignment or just once in a while in the code?

Comment: I don't think forcing a deletion before reassignment is going to do much if anything. The only workflow to *possibly* consider is delete immediately after you think you are done with it ... not to save memory, but if you use the name `"df"` a lot then to preclude you from using the wrong `df`. That is, `df <- data.frame(...); func(df); rm(df); if (cond) { df <- data.frame(...2.); }; func2(df);`. Though a little sloppy, without the `rm(df)` the call to `func2` will happily do *something*, likely with the wrong data; it should instead error, and the `rm` will ensure that error here.

Comment: added the warning messages and a sample query statement that generates such warnings

Comment: when I use df and I will not used it any more rm(list='df') ; gc(); and then redefine df. There is an improvement using big arrays than if you don't use gc().